# How bowse .onion sites with a router (raspberrypi) without tor browser

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, raspberry-pi, routers

Can we use a raspberry pi for accessing .onion site with the tor config ?

I see some tutorials that add in that conf file

VirtualAddrNetwork
AutomapSuffixes .onion,.exit
AutomapOnResolve 1

but that don't seem to work with my internet browser like firefox

Have you any issues ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Firefox to access .onion sites you need to allow this explicitly in about:config - network.dns.blockDotOnion must be set to "false" there. Obviously you need a tor instance running to which you connect and which will provide access to the Tor network.

See https://www.spaetzle.info/tor-wlan-with-raspberry-pi-3/ for some background on the whole setup.

Answer (score 0):

Could you decide if you want it without (title) or with (body) tor browser?

Anyway, I would configure `SOCKSPort` in tor and configure my browser to use it. Proxy autoconfig could be very helpful here, here is what I use with my firefox:

```
function FindProxyForURL(url, host)
{
  if(shExpMatch(host, "*.onion"))
  {
    return "SOCKS <tor sock host>:9050";
  }
  else
  {
    return "DIRECT";
  }
}
```

EDIT: You need network.proxy.socks_remote_dns set to true for this to work. I believe it is equivalent to setting "Proxy DNS when using SOCKS v5" in Preferences -> General -> Network Proxy -> Settings... dialog.

Comment: Thank's for the response. I try your configurations but that don't seem to work, maybe because I rout the traffic thought tor with my raspberry pi router.